# VBScript how to check what a drive is mapped to

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to check if a drive is mapped to a certain spot, and map it there if its not.  How can I check where a drive is mapped?  I'm planning on stopping the script if it's  mapped to the wrong spot, and using `subst D: C:\folder` if it's not mapped (which is what I wanted) or just continuing on if it's mapped to where I want (`C:\folder` for now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9zt39at(v=vs.85).aspx

```
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set oDrives = WshNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives
Set oPrinters = WshNetwork.EnumPrinterConnections

WScript.Echo "Network drive mappings:"

For i = 0 to oDrives.Count - 1 Step 2
    WScript.Echo "Drive " & oDrives.Item(i) & " = " & oDrives.Item(i+1)
Next

WScript.Echo 

WScript.Echo "Network printer mappings:"
For i = 0 to oPrinters.Count - 1 Step 2
    WScript.Echo "Port " & oPrinters.Item(i) & " = " & oPrinters.Item(i+1)
Next
```